# How do you preserve a complex C++ namespace in a Cython wrapper?

Tags: python, c++, namespaces, wrapper, cython

I'm in the process of writing a Cython wrapper for a complex C++ library. I think I've mostly figured out how to write the necessary .pxd and .pyx files. My problem now is that although my C++ program has about 100 separate namespaces, the namespace of the Cython-compiled python library is totally flat.

For example, if I have this in my .pxd file:

```
cdef extern from "lm/io/hdf5/SimulationFile.h" namespace "lm::io::hdf5":
    cdef cppclass CppHdf5File "lm::io::hdf5::Hdf5File":
        ...
```

and this in my .pyx file:

```
cdef class Hdf5File:
    cdef CppHdf5File* thisptr 
    ...
```

then the Cython-compiled Python library contains a class named Hdf5File. Ideally, I'd like the Python to contain a lm.io.hdf5.Hdf5File class (i.e. a Hdf5File class in a lm.io.hdf5 module). In other words, I'd like it if there was a way to translate the C++ :: scoping operator into the Python . dot operator.

Is there a way to get Cython to play nicely with my existing C++ namespaces?

Comment: have you tried `from mypxd cimport lm` in your `.pyx` file? You should then be able to use `lm.io.hdf5.Hdf5File` in the same `.pyx` file for example, but I don't have a machine to try it now. See [this](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Hef7AAAAQBAJ&pg=PT123&lpg=PT123&dq=cython+handle+namespaces&source=bl&ots=YKmbCb9QDn&sig=-Fzuw3J7CD_1uEjvFzLFFrB7fwg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IIOzVICjDszgaNamgugP&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=cython%20handle%20namespaces&f=false) example and [this](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#declaring-a-c-class-interface) about nested namespaces

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `.pyx` file is named `source.pyx`. I would write a `setup.py` as below:

```py
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension(
        name='lm.io.hdf5',
#             ^^^^^^^^^^   -- note the name here
        sources=[
            'path/to/source.pyx',
            # other sources like c++ files ...
        ],
        # other options ...
    ),
]

# Call `setup` as you wish, e.g.:
#setup(
#    ext_modules=cythonize(extensions, language_level='3'),
#    zip_safe=False,
#)
```

This will generate `lm/io/hdf5.so` or like if compilation is successful.
Then in Python, you may import like this:

```py
from lm.io.hdf5 import Hdf5File
```

Reference: [setuptools doc](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html#setuptools.Extension) (doc for `name` field)